# Generating URL in CLI

Tags: jroute, router

Can anybody shed some light how to generate an url in Joomla command-line application.

Seems that budget was cut off at Joomla routing development because:

`JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=document&tmpl=component');`

results in:

`cli/component/mycomponent/?view=document&tmpl=component`

Via web it is:

`/et/component/mycomponent/?view=document&tmpl=component`

Or am I missing something?

Edit:

I could obtain hostname from `JUri::base()` after I had set `live_site` in configuration (weird property name considering that there exists also `site_url`).

Comment: Are you saying the same call to jroute in the site application produced a different url? Could you perhaps add some more details to your question.

Comment: Sorry, my question was little bit wrong (edited). Via web the result is `/et/component/mycomponent/?view=document&tmpl=component`. Via command line the result is `cli/component/mycomponent/?view=document&tmpl=component` (notice no leading slash and incorrect locale).

Comment: Am experiencing similar, though in my case, I simply get the 'cli' prefix on my URls for command-line use, and not for web. I have no equivalent of your '/et'.

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit around with that the last hour and the way you do seems to be right. Maybe you can share all the relevant code here?

This could also be related to that current Joomla! issue which results in similar URLs containing /administrator/ even if a frontend URL is generated:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/20070

The release lead of Joomla answered there something like that this (maybe) is something which can not get fixed in J!3.8 as a alternate solution he wrote:

> helper method that parses and removes the /administrator segment.

Probably this could also be a temporarily solution to remove/replace your 'cli' with 'et'. Not sexy, but if your issue is related to that broken Router issue there seems no other clean way to do right now.